# Driver not found with SQL Server even set class path in windows

Tags: java, sql-server, windows, jdbc, playframework

our teammates got some environment problem of the jdbc driver in our project.

We tried all the path setting with [MS doc.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57175) ,also set .jre file to environment path.

Also double confirmed all the files version in same with the project.

But when it run up in the local server , it always can't fix the error.

We really want to know the **detail process** to set the driver.

Our project environment config:

- Java SDK 1.7
- JDBC Driver 7.0
- play framework 1.2.7

Thanks first to everyone who helped us.

[image]

Comment: don't put text as an image, put it as a text

Comment: @ Dmitrij Kultasev Thx for the advice, I noted. But can you tell me  where I can edit it?

Comment: it is down to the tags http://prntscr.com/oiuhys There could be some limitations due to the rating.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this error would occur if the jdbc jar is not found on the build path your application.

Can you provide more detail about your project detail environment (standalone or J2EE app) and IDE
Can you check the build path of your application.

Comment: Hello @SJN  our project it working standalone .
And we are using the intelliJ to be the IDE , and the SDK can connect with the project. so it can be worked.
But when I open the browser to the main page. It can't get the driver path ,so can't complied .
We set the path in Program Files , and add in the environment path already.